# how to reverse a stack

Tags: c++, stack

I have an assignment where I am suppose to take a single stack, show the output and then reverse it to show the output.

**Its suppose to look like this**

```
Stack:
262 115 74 26 34 243 22 734 113 121
Stack Reversed:
121 113 734 22 243 34 26 74 115 262
```

**Instead mine is coming out like this**

```
Stack:
262 115 74 26 34 243 22 734 113 121 121 113 734 22 243 34 26 74 115 262
Stack Reversed:
```

Can someone please look at my code and see what is going on. I have tried quite a few things but cannot get anything to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "linkedStack.h"

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
void printStack(linkedStackType<Type>& stack);

template <class Type>
void reverseStack(linkedStackType<Type>& stack);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // Declare stack variables
   linkedStackType<int> stack;

   // Add some data to the stack
   stack.push(121);
   stack.push(113);
   stack.push(734);
   stack.push(22);
   stack.push(243);
   stack.push(34);
   stack.push(26);
   stack.push(74);
   stack.push(115);
   stack.push(262);

   cout << "\nStack:\n   ";
   printStack(stack);

   reverseStack(stack);

   cout << "\nStack Reversed:\n   ";
   printStack(stack);

   cout << "\n\n** Press any key to continue **\n";
   getchar();

   return 0;
}

template <class Type>
void printStack(linkedStackType<Type>& stack)
{
   Type item;
   linkedStackType<Type> tmpStack = stack;

   while (stack.isEmptyStack() == false)
   {
      item = stack.top();
      stack.pop();
      cout << item << " ";
   }

   stack = tmpStack;



 }

template <class Type>
void reverseStack(linkedStackType<Type>& stack)
{
  Type item;
   linkedStackType<Type> tmpStack;

   while (stack.isEmptyStack() == false)
   {
      item = stack.top();
      stack.pop();
      tmpStack.push(item);
   }

   while (tmpStack.isEmptyStack() == false)
   {
      item = tmpStack.top();
      tmpStack.pop();
      stack.push(item);
      cout << item;  

   }

   stack = tmpStack;


   return;
}
```

Comment: It will be very difficult to help you without being able to see the code behind `linkedStackType`.

Comment: Not the solution, but the code copies the stack four times. It's easy to get this down to two copies. It can be done with only one copy.

Comment: @sharth: Actually, at least one bug is in the code shown, so that's less of an issue than it'd normally be.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not 100%, but I imagine your code will work if you delete the second while loop of `reverseStack`.

```
template <class Type>
void reverseStack(linkedStackType<Type>& stack)
{
   Type item;
   linkedStackType<Type> tmpStack;

   while (stack.isEmptyStack() == false)
   {
      item = stack.top();
      stack.pop();
      tmpStack.push(item);
   }

   //while (tmpStack.isEmptyStack() == false)
   //{
   //   item = tmpStack.top();
   //   tmpStack.pop();
   //   stack.push(item);
   //   cout << item;
   //}

   stack = tmpStack;
   return;
}
```

Comment: Yep!  This change produces the desired output.  100%

Answer (score 1):

You have an extraneous print loop in reverseStack() which prints the values in the wrong place. In addition this print loop clears your tmpStack. This explains the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `while` loop empties `tmpStack`, but then you assign the now-empty stack to `stack`, so you just have an empty stack.

Comment: @SongWang: no, the stack is never doubled.  It's simply printed twice before it's erased entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. That makes sense. I am sitting here trying to figure out what to add and its as simple as taking away items.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Mooing Duck. Song Wang, yeah, that tripped me up at first too, but then I saw that `Stack Reversed` didn't have anything below it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to reverse the std::stack content:

```
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>    

template <class T>
class _stack : public std::stack<T>
{
    public:
        void reverse()
        {
            std::reverse(this->c.begin(),this->c.end());
        }
};
    
template <class T>
bool reverseStack(std::stack<T> & stack)
{
    bool ret = false;
    auto * s = reinterpret_cast<_stack<T>*> (&stack);
    if(s)
    {
        s->reverse();
        ret = true;
     }
     return ret;
}
    
int main()
{
   std::stack<int> stack;
   stack.push(1);
   stack.push(2);
   stack.push(3);
   stack.push(4);
   stack.push(5);
    
   reverseStack(stack);
}
```

You can use the same approach  to access the cointeiner and print the values using iterators.

Answer (score -1):

```
void sortStack(struct stack **s)  
{  
if (!isEmpty(*s))  
  {  
    int x = pop(s);  
    sortStack(s);  
    sortedInsert(s, x);  
  }  
}  

void sortedInsert(struct stack **s, int x)  
{  
  if (isEmpty(*s) || x > top(*s))  
  {  
    push(s, x);  
    return;  
  }  
int temp = pop(s);  
sortedInsert(s, x);  
push(s, temp);  
}
```

Comment: Some description about your code would be nice for later follow-up.